# Why is there empty quotation marks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, char, quotation-marks

Given a string, return a string where for every char in the original, there are two chars.

`double_char('The')` → `'TThhee'`

`double_char('AAbb')` → `'AAAAbbbb'`

`double_char('Hi-There')` → `'HHii--TThheerree'`

Solution:

```py
    def double_char(str):
      double_char = ""
      for i in range(len(str)):
        double_char += str[i]*2
      return double_char
```

Hello, I'm new here, and it's my first time discovering this website and adding a question, so I'm sorry if it's a bit unclear.
Can someone please explain this one in detail ? Like why it has empty quotation marks?

Comment: You have to create an empty string at first, to be able to add characters to this string later. Then, for every letter, you add that letter twice. Last step: you return the new string

Comment: to instantiate variable with empty string which is initial value.

Comment: made pythonic: https://ideone.com/0ml7Ov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def double_char(str):            # function double_char takes argument str
    double_char = ""             # create an empty string assign to variable double_char. In python you put "" or '' around text that you want as a string (text).
    for i in range(len(str)):    # iterate from 0 to length of string
        double_char += str[i]*2  # append character at position i from str and duplicate it
    return double_char           # return double_char
```

Answer (score 0):

`double_char = ""` Create an empty string, to be able to add characters to it.

`for i in range(len(str)):` For every letter

`double_char += str[i]*2`  Add this letter twice to the string

`return double_char`  Return the string